# Exim error: no usable sender address

Tags: ubuntu, exim

I have installed exim 4 in Ubuntu. I am trying to send an email to myself to test if I have configured it correctly. When I check the log file, I see the following error:

```
2023-07-17 13:45:28 1qLMfF-0001Kp-Dz <= <username>@ETC_MAILNAME U=<username> P=local S=308
2023-07-17 13:45:28 1qLMfF-0001Kp-Dz ** <email_address>: Unrouteable address

2023-07-17 13:45:28 1qLMfQ-0001Kx-7f 1qLMfQ-0001Kx-7f bad addresses found in headers
2023-07-17 13:45:28 1qLMfQ-0001Kx-7f Error while reading message with no usable sender address (R=1qLMfF-0001Kp-Dz): at least one malformed recipient address: <username>@ETC_MAILNAME - malformed address: _MAILNAME may not follow <username>@ETC
2023-07-17 13:45:28 1qLMfF-0001Kp-Dz Process failed (1) when writing error message to <username>@ETC_MAILNAME (frozen)
```

At first, I tried to modify the `/etc/email-addresses` file like this:

```
<my_username>: <my_email_address>
```

In addition, I modified the file `/etc/mailname` where I wrote my email adrress.

However, I still see the same error.

It seems that for some reason it does not expand the variable `ETC_MAILNAME` into my email address. Where should I put my email address in the configuration? What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Please tell in your question how exactly you configured `exim4` during the interactive configuration and by manually editing configuration files. Do you want to use email accounts at an ISP or do you want to self-host everything? Please show real values instead of placeholders. You can replace your domain with something like `example.com`, but keep the format of all values in order to avoid hiding errors. `/etc/mailname` should contain a host name not an email address.